# printing javascript variables on html Page

Tags: javascript

Hello Great Stackoverflow Coders, I want to print javascript variables from an image tag. The only working method I know is to use inner html and then print it in a div. Is there any way I can print the variable in an image tag.

```
<script>
var photo = "picture1.png";
document.getElementById("pic").innerHTML = photo;
</script>
```

Here is what am trying to achieve but could not get it to work.

```
<img src="pic">
```

Thanks

Comment: "Print javascript variables from image tag"? From the code it looks like you are trying to set the src if an img tag?

Comment: try this document.getElementById("pic").src="photo";

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
var photo = "picture1.png";
document.getElementById("pic").src = photo;
</script>
```